# Entity Framework add-migration removes Sql() block I manually added

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to clean up an old project as it is moved in to MVC5 and I need to change a lot of values before a migration. For example, strings Y need to become a 1.

It looks like

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        Sql(@"
            UPDATE [pgm].[dbo].[t_openposition] SET breakfast = 0 WHERE breakfast='N';);
        AlterColumn("dbo.t_openposition", "breakfast", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.t_openposition", "discount", c => c.String(maxLength: 255, unicode: false));
    }
```

Next, when I then run update-database, it fails and warns me that I need to add a migration because things have changed. However, if I run, say, add-migration, it removes that block of Sql()

Answer (score 0):

The thing about `Add-Migration` is that it auto-generates that file for you, the `timestamp_name_migration.cs` thing. So when you run `Add-Migration NameOfMigration` and you've previously run `Add-Migration NameOfMigration`, the file will be generated again and any code you've written will be lost. The whole point of the migration thing is that all this stuff is done for you and that you shouldn't have to do any SQL. That explains why you lose that line.

For the error, in your case, as soon as that first SQL statement is executed, the model no longer matches the database and EF will not continue and throw that error. The idea is that they're always in sync.

I see that you're trying to edit the database (and not lose the data) and change the schema (looks like a column from `string` to `bool`).

Here's what I recommend if you can't nuke the database:

Carefully execute all these statements in SSMS until you're happy, then reverse engineer the database model (#3 here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620(v=vs.113).aspx) and delete your old code one. This will give you a new code first model that will be in sync with the database and everything will be good.

And if you can nuke the database:

1. Delete all your tables in your database including `__MigrationHistory`.
2. Delete all your migrations *excluding* the `Configuration` class with the `Seed` method.
3. Make your changes to your model
4. `Add-Migration Initial`
5. `Update-Database`

Then everything will be good.